# Spring rest resource change path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-rest

I currently have a repository annotated with `@RepositoryRestResource`. I'm adding the following:

```
@RestResource(path="make", rel = "make", description = @Description("Get vehicles by make"))
List<Vehicle> findByMake(@Param("make") String make);
```

This works fine but the path by default is `api/vehicles/search/make`.

How can I remove the `/search` part and just have the path be `api/vehicles/make`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. I make some research in Spring Data Rest source code.

There are constants that uses for URI building in [`RepositorySearchController.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositorySearchController.java#L73-L74):

```
private static final String SEARCH = "/search";
private static final String BASE_MAPPING = "/{repository}" + SEARCH;
```

And **[here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositorySearchController.java#L170-L184)** is the action method that handle requests by services with `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation. So as you can see the `search` part is hardcoded and couldn't be changed.

Comment: And what about a Servlet *Filter*?